# How to serve the front-end in a Spring microservice architecture?

Tags: java, microservices, spring, distributed-computing

I want to create the following distributed system: Spring back-end microservices containing the domain logic, a UAA (authentication) service, a Eureka service registry/discovery, a Spring Cloud Config service, and a Zuul API gateway.

I am wondering what is the proper way of serving an Angular front-end application. At the moment I am serving it as a standalone application calling the API gateway, but I have seen other approaches like serving Angular from a Spring Boot service registered in Eureka, or serving it from the API gateway itself*. I am leaning towards the latter, as it feels more structured, since the front-end is intended to only consume the API gateway, and nothing else.

*In fact, generating a front-end app with [JHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/) implements this approach: it creates a `webapp` folder in the `src/main` directory of the Zuul application.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what proper way of doing this is, I can tell you want **I don't want to do**.

1. I don't want to bring down a service/API gateway to deploy frontend.
2. I don't want to wait for the service to start up (zuul or boot).
3. Worry how many of instances to deploy, to handle the load.

There are things **I want to do**.

1. Deploy it independently of the backend.
2. Configure it once.
3. Have no downtime while doing so (in the end, it's just files).

So as a result of this, I configure the frontend with services such as Amazon S3 and then remove the cache of the index.html when new version is deployed, not affecting boot/zool.